# Valgrind detects reachable blocks even after freeing malloc space in C (cs50 Problem Set 4 Recover)

Tags: c, memory, malloc, valgrind, cs50

I have completed the Problem Set 4 of cs50 called recover. You will see below that i have used malloc for a char* called sfile. In the end of the file i remember to free the allocated space (aka sfile) and close the 2 documents that i have opened.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover IMAGE\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%s", argv[1]);

    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf(" can't be opened for reading\n");
        return 2;
    }

    unsigned char arr[512];

    int s = 0;

    FILE *output_file = NULL;

    char *sfile = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);

    while (fread(arr, sizeof(char), 512, file) != 0)
    {

        if (arr[0] == 0xff && arr[1] == 0xd8 && arr[2] == 0xff && (arr[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0)
        {
            sprintf(sfile, "%03i.jpg", s);

            output_file = fopen(sfile, "w");

            s++;
        }

        if (output_file != NULL)
        {
            fwrite(arr, sizeof(char), 512, output_file);
        }

    }

    free(sfile);

    fclose(output_file);
    fclose(file);


    return 0;
}
```

However when running check50 which is a tool to check if you completed all the points of the exercise, i got only one red message indicating that valgrind has detected memory errors. So my next step was to run:

```
$ valgrind ./recover card.raw
```

this is what returned:

```
==53590== HEAP SUMMARY:
==53590==     in use at exit: 23,128 bytes in 49 blocks
==53590==   total heap usage: 1,091 allocs, 1,042 frees, 240,880 bytes allocated
==53590== 
==53590== 23,128 bytes in 49 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==53590==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==53590==    by 0x4A076CD: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:65)
==53590==    by 0x4A076CD: fopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (iofopen.c:86)
==53590==    by 0x109304: main (recover.c:37)
==53590== 
==53590== LEAK SUMMARY:
==53590==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==53590==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==53590==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==53590==    still reachable: 23,128 bytes in 49 blocks
==53590==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==53590== 
==53590== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==53590== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The program works perfectly and this is the only problem there is left.

I have looked at [cs50 recover sill reachable but no valgrind error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77028437/cs50-recover-sill-reachable-but-no-valgrind-error), but I could not really understand it since his code is spaghetti code to my eyes (No offence!!)

I am still new to C and having a programming background in Python makes it difficult for me to understand anything that has to do with memory, since python is much more straight forward.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: OT: Is there a reason for `char *sfile = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);` instead of plain `char sfile[8];`?

Comment: ... or `char sfile[ 128 ];` With Gb of memory, why scrimp (and risk overflowing when there are > 999 targets in the source file?

Comment: What happens if the last successful read doesn't get a full 512 bytes?

Comment: @Fe2O3 there are 50 .jpg target files. Why did you make an array of 128 bytes?

Comment: @Fe203 nothing happens since after i iterate through the whole file the last read will get into the sfile and the while loop will eventually end

Comment: @Savvidaios Regarding the array size, there's just no need to be cheap. Better be safe and prepared for future problems. And if the input file size isn't a multiple of `512`, the last bytes will be lost, you will not read them and you will not write them to the output. Always be prepared. CS50 is kind of bad in that regards, because it presents things in a much too nice way, you need to learn that things in real life isn't often that nice.

Comment: Why 128? Experience. It costs nothing (in this program) to avoid overrunning the buffer. `%03d` specifies the _minimum_ width that `sprintf()` can generate, not the maximum. Experience shows the code should make allowances for things not going according to plan. But, who needs to listen to experience???

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I appreciate the kind notice. It is true that CS50 presents C very Beginner friendly so that they can pave the way to understanding the language. Thank you a lot for the answer below !

Comment: @Fe2O3 Of course i am willing to listen to experience that is the reason i wanted to know why use 128 bytes. Its my first time using sprintf and i didnt know that %03d specifies the minimum nor that 128 would be more that enough. As i have stated above the thought of memory is a totally new region for me to learn. Thank you a lot for the explanation!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
output_file = fopen(sfile, "w");
```

will happen multiple times. But you only close `output_file` once.

You need to add a check to see if `output_file` is not `NULL` and then close the file first, before opening it again.

---

The main hint is that the leak happens in `fopen`. Which is easy to see in the Valgrind output.

Comment: You are totally right! I changed it to : if (output_file == NULL)
            {
                output_file = fopen(sfile, "w");
            }
            else
            {
                fclose(output_file);
                output_file = fopen(sfile, "w");
            }
and it worked perfectly! Thank a lot!!

Comment: @Savvidaios Suggest you acquaint yourself with `freopen()`... Pity that function _requires_ the file to be open... Would be nice if it worked like `realloc()` as `malloc()`...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I will check it out. Thanks !!